# RegEx: fixed length letters followed by numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex that allows to enter lets say 5 symbols - letters or digits but letters should be always followed by digits?

It needs to be something like `[0-5 letters][0-5 digits]` but the total length of the string should be 5 symbols.

The problem is that I can't manage to limit the length of the string after applying first two expressions.

I've tried something like

```
^[a-zA-Z]{0,5}[0-9]{0,5}$
```

but it is not what I want - it doesn't restrict length.

Examples:

- AAAAA
- AA777
- 77777

Examples that shouldn't match:

- AAA7A
- 77AAA
- AAA777

Comment: So, what have you tried? What problem are you running into? We're not here to do your work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a look ahead assertion `(?=.{5}$)` at the beginning of regex to assert the string is always length of five:

```js
var samples = ['AAAAA',         // match
               'AA777',         // match
               '77777',         // match
               'AAA7A',         // doesn't match pattern
               '77AAA',         // doesn't match pattern
               'AAA777'         // match the pattern but doesn't match the length
              ]

console.log(
  samples.map(s => /^(?=.{5}$)[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*$/.test(s))
)
```

Comment: I like this answer I was going to use a more complex assertion.

Comment: @AlexCollins Thank you.

Comment: Though you could use `[a-zA-Z0-9]` instead of `.` in the lookahead to reject everyting non-alphanumeric right away.